# Android - How doesn't start activity when user clicks a notification in bar

Tags: android, android-intent

I don't want to start activity when user clicks on notification in status bar when activity A is showing, but when A has been destroyed or invisiable, activity has been start normally when user click a notification.

How can I do? Thanks!

Update, this is my code to show Notification:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(GCMReceiver.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE,
            notiMessage);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this.context);      
    mBuilder.setContentText(message);

    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);       
    mNotificationManager.notify(KEY_PUSH_NOTIFICATION, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Show the BroadcastReceiver or your PendingIntent Code.

Comment: Post your code for notification.

Comment: I've just updated code

Comment: Post your manifest please

Answer (score 0):

You can init your pendingIntent like below for not opening class when user click on notification:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = 
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 

        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

Comment: Could you explain more details about that? Because sometime activity has been started and sometime not when notification clicked

Comment: you can not change notifiction after creating it.

Comment: You mean it's impossible? Any other suggest?

Comment: my suggestion is use Broadcast Receiver. put custom intent action in pending Intent.on receive of that action check the current activity.If current activity is not your main activity then start it!!